# In Xcode changing the value from build settings in xcconfig is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, build-settings, xcconfig

I have my project and my appConfig.xcconfig file.

I would like to change the `Debug_Information_Format` value in the `build settings`.

What I did is

```
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf-with-dsym
```

I am using one single xcconfig for both `Debug` and `Release`, but when I run the target in debug mode, Xcode didn't generate the dSYM file for me if in the `build settings` tag this value is `dwarf`.

Also if I change it to `dwarf-with-dsym` in `build settings` tag when it was set to `DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf` in the `xcconfig`, it will still generate dSYM file.

So it's like it's not controlling the value.

I also tried:

```
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT[config=debug] = dwarf-with-dsym
```

Still cannot change the value set in `build-settings` tag.

Comment: According to this post: https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/xcconfig_guide.html#VariableSubstitution , I am thinking this is impossible?